# Linux: How to modify a .dmg file

Tags: linux, macos, 7-zip, dmg-image

I called

```
 file file.dmg
```

and got the message `zlib compressed data`. I extract the `dmg` file with `7z`:

```
7z x file.dmg
```

and then I create a directory `test` mount the hfs file

```
mount -t hfsplus -o loop 4.hfs test
```

then I modify the data  and add few files and want to build later a new `dmg` file with my modified data, but how?

Comment: How about: `genisoimage -D -V "Volume Label" -no-pad -r -apple -o <dest.dmg> <src>`.

Comment: But if I run ``file`` it returns ``test.dmg: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Volume Label'``.

Comment: It's probably an uncompressed dmg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are some references that I found for creating a `dmg` file
(but have no experience with).

[**libdmg-hfsplus**](https://github.com/planetbeing/libdmg-hfsplus)

The libdmg-hfsplus repository, which includes a number of portable libraries and utilities that manipulate the HFS+ file system and DMG images, is still in its experimental stage, so it doesn’t contain any utility that allows building Apple’s DMG images from scratch, but can convert an ISO file.

The following commands were found in the article
[How to Build DMG Files for Windows-Based Applications on Linux](https://blog.techinline.com/2017/12/14/how-to-build-dmg-files-for-windows-based-applications-on-linux/),
to build from source using a forked version of the library:

```
    sudo apt-get install gcc
    sudo apt-get install g++
    sudo apt-get install cmake
    sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
    sudo apt-get install genisoimage
    git clone https://github.com/hamstergene/libdmg-hfsplus.git
    cd libdmg-hfsplus
    cmake .
    make
```

The resulting program will be found in `dmg/dmg` and can be used like this:

```
    # Generates IMG disk image with the help of genisoimage
    genisoimage -D -V "SetMeitClient" -no-pad -r -apple -file-mode 0777 -o generated.img original && \
    # Converts IMG into DMG ($dmgPath is the path that points to the DMG utility)
    dmg generated.img generated.dmg
```

[**github create-dmg**](https://github.com/andreyvit/create-dmg)

This open-source project is described as :

> A shell script to build fancy DMGs.

I found testimonies in several places saying that it does the job.

[**node-appdmg**](https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg)

This open-source project requires `npm` and is described as:

> Generate beautiful DMG-images for your OS X applications.

There are also testimonies for its working well.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good answer!

Comment: A bit too late for the bounty.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought you got the points.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 0):

- Boot your favorite version of Mac OSx using your favorite Hypervisor.
- Mount the DMG
- Using Disk Utility, make a copy of the DMG that is writable.
- Unmount the original DMG
- Mount the new writable copy.

Now you can use the mounted DMG like any other filesystem: copy, delete, rename, whatever you need.